# Android Studio: pasar el valor de un edittext a un textview de otra actividad

Tags: android-studio, activity

Quiero pasar el valor que le pone un usuario a un edittext a un textview que se encuentra en otra actividad (la textview se encuentra en la principal, y el edittext en la segunda).

Este código pertenece a la segunda actividad, donde se encuentra el edittext donde el usuario pone un string y este se debe de pasar a un Textview de la MainActivity:

```
public class Activitat2 extends AppCompatActivity {

Button botoAcceptar;
Button botoCancelar;
EditText edittextCarrer;
TextView valorCarrer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitat2);

    widgets();

    botoCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activitat2.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

    botoAcceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dadesAfegidesUsuari();
            startActivity(new Intent(Activitat2.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

public void widgets() {
    botoAcceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botoAcceptar);
    botoCancelar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botoCancelar);
    edittextCarrer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextCarrer);
    valorCarrer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valorUsuariCarrer);
}


public void dadesAfegidesUsuari() {
    if(edittextCarrer.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0){
        valorCarrer.setText(edittextCarrer.getText());
    }
}}
```

Básicamente cuando el usuario ha puesto un string en el edittext "edittextCarrer", al clicar al botón "botoAcceptar" debe de aparecer la MainActivity con el textview llamado "valorCarrer" con el string pasado por "edittextCarrer".

Parece algo bastante básico, y cuando he trabajado con cosas así en una misma actividad no he tenido problemas. Pero con esto no hay manera, imagino que hay algo que hago mal en la función "dadesAfegidesUsuari" que es la que se encarga de pasar los datos.

Aclaro que los id y demás están bien puesto, los detecta todos. El programa crashea al darle al botón aceptar, y me indica que el problema está en la siguiente línea:

```
valorCarrer.setText(edittextCarrer.getText());
```

La excepción que aparece en el monitor es:

> Process: practica.m08_eac1, PID: 2707
>                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                                           at practica.m08_eac1.Activitat2.dadesAfegidesUsuari(Activitat2.java:73)
>                                                                           at practica.m08_eac1.Activitat2$2.onClick(Activitat2.java:47)
>                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Cual es tu actividad principal? Y, donde se encuentra el `TextView` que tiene el id `R.id.valorUsuariCarrer`, en el layout del `MainActivity` o del `Activitat2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en tu mensaje de error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object

Cuando obtienes la referencia del `TextView` con id `valorUsuariCarrer`, en realidad se obtiene un valor null:

```
valorCarrer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valorUsuariCarrer);
```

y al llamar el método setText sobre esta instancia provoca el error:

```
valorCarrer.setText(edittextCarrer.getText());
```

**Para solucionar este error, tienes que asegurar que el `TextView` con id `valorUsuariCarrer` en realidad se encuentre dentro de tu layout `activity_activitat2.xml`**

Ok , si lo que deseas es enviar variables entre Activities, esto se realiza mediante un Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("valoredittext", edittextCarrer.getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

En la Activity que recibe estos valores, los puedes obtener mediante el [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html):

```
 //Recibe valor.
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 String valor_recibido = b.getString("valoredittext");
 //Agrega valor a TextView.
 myTextView.setText(valor_recibido);
```

Comment: MUCHAS gracias, después de muchas horas justo esto era lo que estaba haciendo mal-no ponía. Ahora ya me va a la perfección, gracias!

Comment: Excelente @MarcusF , saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que el objeto TextView valorCarrer está definido en el layout de la actividad principal, entonces cuando haces:

```
valorCarrer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valorUsuariCarrer);
```

valorCarrer es nulo y claro, al intentar asignarle un valor mediante su método setText te "salta" una excepción porque invocas a un método de un objeto que es null.

Lo que tienes que hacer es lanzar la segunda actividad con el método:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, OPINION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

e implementar el método:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == OPINION_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {...}
    ...}
}
```

El método onActivityResult es el que se ejecuta al volver a la actividad y como ves en los parámetros va un intent, ahí puedes devolver lo que quieras y ya rellenar el TextBox.

Si en la actividad 2 ha ido todo bien, tienes que indicar:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

para que al volver te entre al método onActivityResult.

Miralo un poco más por internet (que yo te lo he explicado deprisa y corriendo) que es muy sencillo de hacer.

También puedes mirar el tema de eventos que es muy interesante y efectivo a la hora de usarlo, pero es más difícil y para lo que necesitas no te hace falta, pero aún así estaría muy bien que lo mirases, aunque sólo sea por saber que existen y lo que son, en un futuro te podría tocas utilizarlos

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esta tarea, Android pone a nuestra disposición los llamados “Intent“. En general, utilizaremos un Intent cuando queramos movernos de una actividad a otra, permitiéndonos a su vez pasar datos desde la Activity en la que estamos hacia la nueva.

```
// Pasaremos de la actividad actual a OtraActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("variable_integer", EditText.Text());//Ejemplo Tipo Int
intent.putExtra("variable_string", EditText.Text()); // Ejemplo Tipo String
intent.putExtra("objeto_float", EditText.Text()); // Ejemplo Tipo Float
startActivity(intent);
```

El código que viene a continuación es el que se ejecutará en la actividad OtraActivity. Se muestran dos formas de recuperar las variables, se puede utilizar la que más convenga en cada ocasión.

```
// Estamos en OtraActivity
int recuperamos_variable_integer = getIntent().getIntExtra("variable_integer");
String recuperamos_variable_string = getIntent().getStringExtra("variable_string");
float recuperamos_variable_float = getIntent().getFloatExtra("objeto_float");
```

//Aquí asignas el valor del string recuperado a tu TextView

```
TextView.Text = recuperamos_variable_string;
```

// O también de esta otra forma

```
// Estamos en OtraActivity
Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int recuperamos_variable_integer = datos.getInt("variable_integer");
String recuperamos_variable_string = datos.getString("variable_string");
float recuperamos_variable_float = datos.getFloat("objeto_float");
```

Fuente: http://jonsegador.com/2012/02/paso-de-datos-variables-entre-actividades-android/